# UseState doesnt change button color immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, use-state

So I created button using looping from React useState

```
  const [booleanMonth,setMonth]=useState([
    {key:0,value:'January',color:'black'},
    {key:1,value:'February',color:'black'},
    {key:2,value:'March',color:'black'},
    {key:3,value:'April',color:'black'},
    {key:4,value:'May',color:'black'},
    {key:5,value:'June',color:'black'},
    {key:6,value:'July',color:'black'},
    {key:7,value:'August',color:'black'},
    {key:8,value:'September',color:'black'},
    {key:9,value:'October',color:'black'},
    {key:10,value:'November',color:'black'},
    {key:11,value:'December',color:'black'}
    ])

  const createButtonMonth = () =>{
    return (<View style={styles.containerForButtons2}>
            {
              booleanMonth.map((item,key) => 
                <View key={item.key} style={styles.buttonFilter3}><Button key={item.key} title={item.value} color={item.color}  value={item.value} 
                onPress={()=>onPressMonthFilter(item.key)}/></View>)
            }
            </View>)
    }
```

and then to change the button's color I'm using this function for toggle button color

```
  const onPressMonthFilter = (keymonth) =>{    
    if(booleanMonth[keymonth].color=='black'){
      booleanMonth[keymonth].color='green'
      setMonth(booleanMonth)
    }else{
      booleanMonth[keymonth].color='black'
      setMonth(booleanMonth)
    }
  }
```

the color's of pressed button doesn't change immediately but when I close some random modal or do a refresh function that I created, the button's color then will change.
I don't know what happens, or how to fix it.

edit : I'm using this and it change the button immediately which is weird, and not the solution that I want, I dont want to loop

```
const onPressMonthFilter = (keymonth) =>{
    let monthChecked = []
    for(var i = 0 ; i<booleanMonth.length ; i ++){
      if(booleanMonth[i].key == keymonth){
          if(booleanMonth[i].color == 'green'){
            booleanMonth[i].color = 'black'
          }else{
            booleanMonth[i].color = 'green'
          }
        }
        monthChecked.push(booleanMonth[i])
      }
      setMonth(monthChecked)
}
```

Comment: You're mutating the object directly, which means React isn't aware of the change since it just checks for object equality. All React sees is the same object as before. Therefore it doesn't get re-rendered until something else is properly changed. Whenever you change something, create a new object with those changes and pass it in.

Answer (score 2):

Having `let monthCheck=booleanMonth` does NOT create a copy of the state. It stores a reference to that state array. So mutating `monthCheck` mutates the state, and that causes the issues you're facing. Your easiest bet here is to use the `.map` method, since that returns a new array, e.g.

```
const onPressMonthFilter = (keymonth) =>{
      setMonth(booleanMonth.map(month => ({
          ...month,
          color: month.key === keymonth ? 'green' : 'black'
      }))
   );
}
```

Comment: removed the monthCheck still not changing

Comment: not the solution but upvoted anyway for efficiency input

Comment: @Bzxnaga ok so is this the specific behaviour you want: A button for each month, all of them initially black. When you click a button, it turns green. If you click another, that turns green and the other selected one turns back to black. and so on

Comment: yes exactly, any other solution other than using useState ?

Comment: Ok well then my solution does work. You can see it working here (few minor changes since it's react, not react native): https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-architecture-6lur2?file=/src/App.js also the new code in your edit *still* mutates the state, don't do that

Comment: sorry , I meant something like checkbox, when I press one button to green others also can turn green, when i press again the green one it change to black.
But I will use your code as my year filter button, big improvement in performance there instead of looping. Thankies ~

Comment: @Bzxnaga oh, well you can achieve checkbox like behaviour with just a few modifications, storing whether the month is "selected" or not. I made another sandbox with those tweaks: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-resonance-f2oob?file=/src/App.js